# Android SQLiteCursor - getString returned value from a null valued column

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

[Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29) API tells that the behavior is defined by the implementation when a null valued column is tried to be accessed and If I go to [SQLiteCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html), the behavior is not documented. Does the `SQLiteCursor` return a `NULL` or throw an `Exception`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7753274/2291

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never mind, I got the problem solved by checking for null value using the [isNull](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#isNull%28int%29) method.

Answer (score -1):

cursor.isEmpty() is working for me.