# Storing dates in SQLite and performing search by date

Tags: android, sqlite, simpledateformat

I want to insert dates like "2013-12-24" in an SQLite database. My requirements include date wise search functionality.

query for table -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LEAD_TIME_TABLE
             (
             LEAD_TIME_ID
             INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
             **LEAD_TIME_VALUE
             DATE NOT NULL,**
             LEAD_TIME_TYPE
            TEXT NOT NULL);
```

When I insert data in this table, the date is parsed like from `2013-12-24` to 
`Tue Dec 24 19:00:00 EST 2013`

This is my method for parsing dates:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
Date date = null;
try {
    date = dateFormat.parse("2013-12-24");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When i am searching with a query such as:

```
select * from lead_time where value between 'Thu Dec 26 13:30:00 EST 2013' and 'Tue Dec 31 13:30:00 EST 2013'
```

In the results I am getting unexpected result. How can i resolve that?

Comment: What results are you getting, and what are you expecting instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` and `DateTime` are not [supported datatypes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) in `SQLite`. As `SQLite` creators themselves [propose](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) we should use string or integer for storing such types. The solution you propose uses `TEXT`.

However, I think that generally it is wrong decision to use string instead of integer, especially if you want to compare. Here is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13694823/1108032) in SO discussing the same. You can also check the recommended solution there. I also support this approach.

Answer (score 0):

For my DB's I use type "LONG" (basically "INT") and store the time in epoch millis. Then you can use an instance of Calendar to set the values of various time intervals needed for your query:

```
select * from lead_time where value between calendar1.getTimeInMillis() and calendar2.getTimeInMillis();
```

Seems to work well but the tables don't have dates that are easily readable. Small price for fast queries and easily portable data IMO.

Answer (score -2):

You can use parameterized queries : [How do I use prepared statements in SQlite in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android)

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("select * from lead_time where value between ? and ?");
stmt.bindDate(1, date1);
stmt.bindDate(2, date2);
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: Bullshit. No `bindDate` method. `Date` is not a type for SQLite