# How to get data Y M D to pass into Hashmap in Android?

Tags: java, android

I would like to get the current date and put into hashmap so I can store it in a database. How do I do that?

For example:

```
 Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();{
 map.put("Speed", speed.gettext.tostring());
 map.put("date",currentdate());

  }
```

Comment: Map<String, Date> map = new HashMap<String, Date>();
map.put("date", new Date());

Comment: Use `new Date().toString()` to retrieve current date as string (with default format)

Comment: hi @Wukash Sorry to add on. What if I got other parameter that is in string. See the edited version. So how do I include the date?

Comment: @fRoStBiT it said newDate() cannot be resolve

Comment: You use `ContentValues` to put into a database, not a HashMap

Comment: @fRoStBiT `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` is the correct way to get the current time as a Date object

Comment: @fRoStBiT Thanks! It work

Comment: @cricket_007 Calendar object is unnecessary here. Creating a Calendar is more expensive

Comment: @cricket_007 Hi could you explain why is it more expensive? :) thanks

Comment: I think @fRoStBiT should answer that.

Comment: @Spotty Method `Calendar.getInstance()` creates new GregorianCalendar object and initializes all its fields (year, month etc.) with current time. `getTime()` creates new `Date` object based on that calendar's time and then we discarding the `Calendar` instance. But we can just create new `Date` object with current time via `new Date()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
Map<String, String>
```

you have no other choice than format the date as string, see SimpleDateFormat. You can use (Simple)DateFormat's format and parse functions to convert date to string and string to date.

But it is not a nice solution, because there are no date type in sqlite. According to  https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html you have 3 options to store date(time):

- TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
- REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
- INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

you can see also:
[Best way to work with dates in Android SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363112/best-way-to-work-with-dates-in-android-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the Year, month and day as below.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); // month starts at 0 and not from 1.
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```