# How to save a Date from DatePicker into SQLite with Android Studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite, date, datepicker

I have a SQLite DB for my Android app project and I would like to save a date from a Date Picker.
TO be as efficient as possible, I cannot insert that date as a String.
So I'm trying to save my date as an Integer or a Long but I check all around the web and nothing clear enough to help me...

Here is my code:

```
   public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        // Do something with the chosen date
        TextView dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newdatepicked);

        // Create a Date variable/object with user chosen date
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
        cal.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);

        Date date = cal.getTime();  // CAN I USE THIS LINE?

        // Format the date using style MEDIUM and FR locale
        DateFormat df_date = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, Locale.FRANCE);
        String dateDF= df_date.format(dateDF);
        // Display the formatted date
        dateView.setText(dateDF);

    }
};
```

And my code to insert all my data:

```
  public void SaveAlert(View v) {

    String Article = tvArticle.getText().toString();
    long DateEntree = calendar.getTimeInMillis(); // This line is working very well
    long DateSortie =                   ;///////// I CANNOT FIND OUT HOW TO HANDLE THIS ...
```

My issue is with DateSortie.

Please let me apologize for my English and thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You show selevted Date in textview. So just save dateDF value as string in Database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can still store it as string and then retrieve them using the format you want for example

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

   /* to display time*/
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");

    /* to display date in the given format */
   DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  

   /*get the date using */
   Date dDate = dateFormatter.parse(yourObject.getTaskDate());

   /*set the date */
   calendar.setTime(dDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know how To insert it with a string but I have read it's better To save it as an integer To order by date for exemple.

Comment: This might  maybe help you to convert your picked date to timestamp using calendar [http://stackoverflow.com/a/13694823/6213163]

Comment: Hi, @Anirudh, thanks for your help, it works fine ;)

Comment: glad that was helpful :)